# How can I center Windows 10 start menu position?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

As when I was composing this question the site suggested me a similar question that suggests an app called [StartOrbMover](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/orb-mover-move-start-button-menu-windows) for Windows 7 that is not updated for Windows 10 and will not function at all.

So basically, I have noticed the existence of the new Windows 11 start menu being moved to the center of the screen, and I wonder if this can be achieved on Windows 10 too with some third-party apps somewhere on the internet.

Are there any apps online that center the start menu?

Comment: You can set the start menu to be a start screen with the "Use Start full screen" option. That way it's centered. 

Answer (score 1):

You can normally do this manually in Windows 10.

According to [How to Center Your Windows 10 Taskbar Icons (Like Windows 11)](https://www.howtogeek.com/736658/how-to-center-your-windows-10-taskbar-icons-like-windows-11/):

> To center Windows 10’s taskbar icons:
>
> 1. First, right-click on your taskbar and deselect “Lock the taskbar.”
>
>    [image: Unlock the Taskbar]
> 2. Next, right-click on the taskbar again, hover your mouse cursor over the “Toolbars” option, and select “Links.” A check mark will appear next to it once it’s been selected.
>
>    [image: Toolbars > Links]
> 3. Right-click on the links section in the taskbar for a third time and make sure that “Show Text” and “Show title” are both checked.
>
>    [image: Right Click on Links]
>
>    [image: Show text and title]
> 4. You should now see “Links” on the right side of the taskbar, with two vertical lines to the left of it.
>
>    [image: Links on Left]
> 5. Move your cursor over the two vertical lines, and then click and drag “Links” to the left side of the taskbar. It should snap to the right of the Windows and Search icons
>
>    [image: Move Links Right]
> 6. Changing the location of “Links” will also force your pinned icons to move to the right side of the taskbar. Use the two vertical lines next to your icons to click and drag them to the center of your taskbar. They won’t snap to the center, so you’ll have to eyeball them
>
>    [image: Move Left Icons to Center]
> 7. Next, right-click on the taskbar and deselect “Show Text” and “Show title.”
>
>    [image: Deselect Text & Title]
> 8. Finally, right-click on the taskbar one last time and select “Lock the Taskbar.”
>
>    [image: Re-Lock the taskbar]

If you wish to center the entire Start Menu you will likely need to use Tablet Mode and / or use third party software.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I am looking for centering the start **menu** in the system, not the icons on the task bar. The start menu is the one where the app tiles and stuff are located at.

Comment: I now you need third party software for Windows 10 and  I think also for Windows 11. No way I see to move the Windows 11 Start Menu. You might try Tablet Mode in both operating systems. I use desktop mode and natively in Desktop you cannot center the start menu (at least not as far as I can see and I have both 10 and 11 right here).

Comment: So that is both my point and my question of whether if there is any third-party software that can accomplish this because I have spent the past 4 weeks looking for native settings to shift the start menu position to the center and found none

Comment: I have looked for this and did not find any. So I think the options I left you are all that is available. I checked settings on both Windows 10 and 11 machines here.

Answer (score 0):

You may only move the taskbar to any of the four corners of
your display:

- Go to *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar*
- Scroll down to "Taskbar location on screen"
- Reset the Taskbar to one of the other screen positions

You may notice unintended differences when the Taskbar is set to the
right or left.

[image]

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I am looking for centering the start **menu** in the system, not the location of the task bar. The start menu is the one where the app tiles and stuff are located at.

Comment: Moving the taskbar will also move the Start menu orb. I don't know of any way of moving it to the middle of the taskbar, at least not on Windows 10. This is not possible at all in Windows 10, not even with the use of skinning utilities.